# How does the Bludger fly in Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

I have been reading Harry Potter for a while now and a question popped into my head out of nowhere. How does the Bludger fly in Quidditch?

Comment: i assumed the same way brooms do, magic. which would then pose the question why the Snitch needs wings

Comment: ..... well, it would have to be magic, wouldn't it?

Comment: Quickly. And hard.

Comment: @Memor-X The Snitch has wings because it replaced the Golden Snidget, a bird which was the “original” Snitch, and was released in Quidditch games until the sport’s popularity made it endangered.

Answer (score 13):

## They’re enchanted to fly.

The first Bludgers were rocks that were enchanted to fly around.

> “Could he have been a Creaothceann player? Was it his idea to bewitch heavy rocks to zoom dangerously around the pitch, inspired by the boulders used in his native game?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

While the modern Bludger is metal instead of rock, they’re still enchanted to behave the way they do.

> “Bludgers are bewitched to chase players indiscriminately. If left to their own devices, they will attack the player closest to them, hence the Beaters’ task is to knock the Bludgers as far away from their own team as possible.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

This would presumably still include their ability to fly.